Ansible: Upgrading Helm plugin based on version
I noticed that a Helm plugin cannot be upgraded, based on version. The only solution I found was to remove the plugin, prior re-installing it with the new version:
- name: Remove plugin
  kubernetes.core.helm_plugin:
    plugin_name: diff
    state: absent

- name: Install plugin
  kubernetes.core.helm_plugin:
    plugin_path: https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
    plugin_version: v3.9.8

Is there a better way to do this?

What happens if you run just one task with state: present and plugin_version different than installed? I had the same problem - the issue is that Helm CLI itself doesn't support this. However, I forgot to check if there's an Ansible module for that so I ended up wrapping the shell commands.

The fact that Ansible has state: present enabled by default, prohibits the plugin upgrade, if I have a different plugin_version. That's why I'm forced to use an additional task.
